# As a moderator, "Delete" in the review queues clears custom flags that you may not have seen

Tags: bug, review, flags, moderator-tools, deleted-posts

Outside of the queue, it makes sense that a moderator deletion would clear any custom flags, since the wafflebar is at the bottom showing all the pending flags and a flag count for all flags. In queues like LQP, there is no wafflebar nor flag count, but moderator deletion still clears any pending custom flags ([example](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/453291)). This makes it possible to miss something important when working the queues, assuming the flag said something other than "delete this".

Note that mods often have a "Delete" option where it's not normally available to non-mods, like in Suggested Edits. I haven't tested this behavior in queues other than LQP however.

Not sure how often this happens, but it's worth keeping in mind if you're a moderator who uses the queues.

Comment: What kind of important information you afraid to miss?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ modflags are supposed to notify of issues a user thinks is important. As a user, if I flag with, for example, "Investigate for voting fraud" or flag that is about a pattern of behaviour, rather than a one-off. I definitely wouldn't be happy for just the post to be deleted without said investigation be done.